# Calling MySQL Stored Procedure using VB6 with OUT Parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, vb6

I have written this procedure in MySQL (Server 5.5)

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `InsertList` $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertList`(IN fName VARCHAR(20), IN fType VARCHAR(3), IN fFood varchar(20), Out fResult int)

BEGIN

  insert into tblguest (firstname, confirm, food) values (fName, fType, fFood);

  select count(id) from tblguest into fResult;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

When I call this procedure from MySQL Query Browser it returns as expected

```sql
Call InsertList ('V1', 'No', 'F1', @result);

Select @result;
```

--> It successfully returns the count of the ids in the table

I wrote the following code in VB6

```vb
Dim res As Integer
On Error GoTo chkErr

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "InsertList"

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("fName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, Text3.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("fType", adVarChar, adParamInput, 3, Text2.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("fFood", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, Text1.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("fResult", adInteger,adParamOutput)

cmd.Execute

res = cmd("fResult")
MsgBox res
Exit Sub

chkErr:

    Select Case Err.Number
        Case Else
            Text4.Text = Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    End Select
```

But the moment it tries to run the statement `cmd.execute` it throws the following error :

> -2147467259 - [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.34]OUT or INOUT argument 4 for routine dbtest.InsertList is not a variable or NEW
>   pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

I have seen codes working for SQL, so is it that MySQL itself has an issue using Stored Procedure with an OUT Parameter?

Comment: Also, please note that if I modify the Procedure and remove the 'OUT' parameter, it runs fine and the data is inserted in the table..so it has to do something with the 'OUT' parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a unsolved bug from MySQL ODBC and C/API

One solution is to execute that using a SQL command with prepared variables:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset 

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.CommandText = "call InsertList(?,?,?,@fResult)"

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("fName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, Text3.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("fType", adVarChar, adParamInput, 3, Text2.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("fFood", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, Text1.Text)

cmd.Execute

'And after that, using the same connection, get the value of 
'@fResult from a single query:

Set rs = cn.Execute("select @fResult as fResult")
MsgBox rs!fResult
```

You will get the expected value.